# Java & Modbus RTU CRC Calculation

Tags: java, android, crc, modbus

I've a Slave modbus board with a C CRC algorithm calculation and I must use the same function with my Master in Java on an android application.

The C function is this:

```
unsigned char ucCRCHi = 0xFF;
unsigned char ucCRCLo = 0xFF;
unsigned short iIndex;

while( len-- ){
     iIndex = ucCRCLo ^ *( ptr++ );
     ucCRCLo = ( unsigned char )( ucCRCHi ^ aucCRCHi[iIndex] );
     ucCRCHi = aucCRCLo[iIndex];
 }
 return ( unsigned short )( ucCRCHi * 256 + ucCRCLo );
```

I've tried with this Java code:

```
public int calc(byte[] buffer, int usDataLen)
{

int uchCRCHi = 0xff;
int uchCRCLo = 0xff;
int uIndex;
int i = 0;

while (i<usDataLen){
    uIndex = uchCRCHi^buffer[i];
    uchCRCHi = uchCRCLo ^ auchCRCHi[uIndex];
    uchCRCLo = auchCRCLo[uIndex];

    i++;  
}

buffer[usDataLen] = (byte)uchCRCHi;
buffer[usDataLen + 1] = (byte)uchCRCLo;
return (usDataLen + 2);
}
```

Think will go well?

Then when I have the CRC result, I must convert the int into two bytes array and then add it at the end of the buffer bytes array. Is it right? 
Thanks at all.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very old question, but I will answer it anyways, maybe it will help someone.

I have not written this code, but I have exhaustively tested it in a number of projects. 

It is from the [Jamod](http://jamod.sourceforge.net/) library.

```
  /* Table of CRC values for high-order byte */
      private final static short[] auchCRCHi = {
        0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0,
        0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41,
        0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0,
        0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40,
        0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1,
        0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41,
        0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1,
        0x81, 0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41,
        0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0,
        0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40,
        0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1,
        0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40,
        0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0,
        0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40,
        0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0,
        0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40,
        0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0,
        0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41,
        0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0,
        0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41,
        0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0,
        0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40,
        0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1,
        0x81, 0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41,
        0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0,
        0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40
      };

      /* Table of CRC values for low-order byte */
      private final static short[] auchCRCLo = {
        0x00, 0xC0, 0xC1, 0x01, 0xC3, 0x03, 0x02, 0xC2, 0xC6, 0x06,
        0x07, 0xC7, 0x05, 0xC5, 0xC4, 0x04, 0xCC, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0xCD,
        0x0F, 0xCF, 0xCE, 0x0E, 0x0A, 0xCA, 0xCB, 0x0B, 0xC9, 0x09,
        0x08, 0xC8, 0xD8, 0x18, 0x19, 0xD9, 0x1B, 0xDB, 0xDA, 0x1A,
        0x1E, 0xDE, 0xDF, 0x1F, 0xDD, 0x1D, 0x1C, 0xDC, 0x14, 0xD4,
        0xD5, 0x15, 0xD7, 0x17, 0x16, 0xD6, 0xD2, 0x12, 0x13, 0xD3,
        0x11, 0xD1, 0xD0, 0x10, 0xF0, 0x30, 0x31, 0xF1, 0x33, 0xF3,
        0xF2, 0x32, 0x36, 0xF6, 0xF7, 0x37, 0xF5, 0x35, 0x34, 0xF4,
        0x3C, 0xFC, 0xFD, 0x3D, 0xFF, 0x3F, 0x3E, 0xFE, 0xFA, 0x3A,
        0x3B, 0xFB, 0x39, 0xF9, 0xF8, 0x38, 0x28, 0xE8, 0xE9, 0x29,
        0xEB, 0x2B, 0x2A, 0xEA, 0xEE, 0x2E, 0x2F, 0xEF, 0x2D, 0xED,
        0xEC, 0x2C, 0xE4, 0x24, 0x25, 0xE5, 0x27, 0xE7, 0xE6, 0x26,
        0x22, 0xE2, 0xE3, 0x23, 0xE1, 0x21, 0x20, 0xE0, 0xA0, 0x60,
        0x61, 0xA1, 0x63, 0xA3, 0xA2, 0x62, 0x66, 0xA6, 0xA7, 0x67,
        0xA5, 0x65, 0x64, 0xA4, 0x6C, 0xAC, 0xAD, 0x6D, 0xAF, 0x6F,
        0x6E, 0xAE, 0xAA, 0x6A, 0x6B, 0xAB, 0x69, 0xA9, 0xA8, 0x68,
        0x78, 0xB8, 0xB9, 0x79, 0xBB, 0x7B, 0x7A, 0xBA, 0xBE, 0x7E,
        0x7F, 0xBF, 0x7D, 0xBD, 0xBC, 0x7C, 0xB4, 0x74, 0x75, 0xB5,
        0x77, 0xB7, 0xB6, 0x76, 0x72, 0xB2, 0xB3, 0x73, 0xB1, 0x71,
        0x70, 0xB0, 0x50, 0x90, 0x91, 0x51, 0x93, 0x53, 0x52, 0x92,
        0x96, 0x56, 0x57, 0x97, 0x55, 0x95, 0x94, 0x54, 0x9C, 0x5C,
        0x5D, 0x9D, 0x5F, 0x9F, 0x9E, 0x5E, 0x5A, 0x9A, 0x9B, 0x5B,
        0x99, 0x59, 0x58, 0x98, 0x88, 0x48, 0x49, 0x89, 0x4B, 0x8B,
        0x8A, 0x4A, 0x4E, 0x8E, 0x8F, 0x4F, 0x8D, 0x4D, 0x4C, 0x8C,
        0x44, 0x84, 0x85, 0x45, 0x87, 0x47, 0x46, 0x86, 0x82, 0x42,
        0x43, 0x83, 0x41, 0x81, 0x80, 0x40
      };

    public static final int[] calculateCRC(byte[] data, int offset, int len) {
    int[] crc = {0xFF, 0xFF};
    int nextByte = 0;
    int uIndex; /* will index into CRC lookup*/ /* table */
    /* pass through message buffer */
    for (int i = offset; i < len && i < data.length; i++) {
      nextByte = 0xFF & ((int) data[i]);
      uIndex = crc[0] ^ nextByte; //*puchMsg++; /* calculate the CRC */
      crc[0] = crc[1] ^ auchCRCHi[uIndex];
      crc[1] = auchCRCLo[uIndex];
    }

    return crc;
  }
```

This code uses a look up table, which is slightly faster than following the vanilla algorithm(Not that it makes much difference to modern CPUs)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get your `Lo`'s and `Hi`'s straight.  Compare your code carefully to the original code.

Then it still may or may not be right, depending on whether the CRC is written little endian or big endian at the end of the stream.  It might be written `Lo`, then `Hi`.  In fact, a quick google search indicates just that.  You should get some examples of streams with correct CRCs to check that, as well as for checking your implementation overall.